# How does apache Http11NioProtocol work?

Tags: tomcat7, nio

I am trying to get benefints from NIO with Tomcat 7 Http11NioProtocol.

I just read some article about it :
[Understanding the Tomcat NIO Connector](https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-tomcat-nio)

And looked through  :[tomcat docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html)

I started simple server with only SimpleServlet which counts number of concurrent threads, wait for 10 seconds and returns empty result :

```
public class SimpleServlet extends HttpServlet {

final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SimpleServlet.class);
private static final AtomicInteger threadCntr = new AtomicInteger();

@Override
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    doGet(req, resp);
}

@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    logger.info("ProxyService doGet threads[" + threadCntr.incrementAndGet() + "]");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(10000L);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        logger.info("end processing");
        threadCntr.decrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

}

Configured tomcat's server.xml for using nio protocol:

```
    <Connector port="8081" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
           maxThreads="200" minSpareThreads="5" maxSpareThreads="5"
           enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="1"
           connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
```

I start sending lightweight requests and monitor it using Java VisualVM:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        new Thread(() -> {
            executeHttp(URL, "test"); // impl hided
        }).start();
        Thread.sleep(10);
    }
}
```

When I ran the test I saw only 200 threads used (and that's ok) 
But client's requests couldn't be processes more than 200 per 10 secs[image]

So, where is the difference between BIO?
Or Have I missed some config?
What is the main feature of Http11NioProtocol ?

Comment: First link is broken.

Comment: Fixed. Try again